# Jenkinsfile (Groovy) URI validator

Tags: url, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, uri, jenkins-groovy

I'm fairly new to Groovy and Jenkins, so hopefully this question is coherent.

I have a Jenkinsfile written in Groovy and would like to validate one of the params as a valid URI. Without writing my own regex check, is there a library I could easily invoke during Jenkins startup?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    try {
        def foo = new java.net.URL("yourURI").openStream()
        if (foo.getClass() == sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream) {
            println 'valid'
            foo.close()
        }
    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        println 'not valid'
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `URL.toUri` is not allowed at least in our setup. (It could possibly be allowed with a separate config.) Apparently opening the url (trying to connect to the host) could be possible, but that feels like it could cause other problems.

I ended up with this:

```
    // Validation URLs in Jenkins script is hard (URL.toUri is banned). This regex roughly matches the subset of
    // URLs we might want to use (and some invalid but harmless URLs). You can get a rough sense what
    // this matches with a generation tool like https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-from-regex .
    def saneUrlPattern = ~/^https:\/\/[-\w]{1,32}(\.[-\w]{1,32}){0,4}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/|(\/[-\w]{1,32}){1,10})?(\?([-\w]{1,32}=[-\w]{0,40}(&[-\w]{1,32}=[-\w]{0,40}){1,8})?)?(#[-\w]{0,40})?$/
    if (!(params.sourceUrl =~ saneUrlPattern)) {
      return [error: "Invalid url ${params.sourceUrl}. A simple https URL is expected."]
    }
```

I realise that trying to validate URLs with a regular expression is difficult. I tried to strike a balance between strict and correct enough validation and a regular expression that has some hope of being understood by looking at it and being reasonably convinced as to what it actually matches.